# When is the resulting item determined when giving material to Obaba?

Tags: golden-sun-dark-dawn

When I give one of the forgeable materials to Obaba, the result is a random new item. At what point is the identity of this new item decided: when I give her the material, when I leave Champa, when I return to Champa, or when I speak to her?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some testing, I found that the item is determined as soon as the material is given to her.